# What is the difference between Product Assets and Reference Entities in Akeneo?

Tags: akeneo

What is the difference between Product Assets and Reference Entities in Akeneo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Product assets are meant to represent images/videos/documents and files in general. While the reference entities are a way to link objects to products (colors, materials, etc).

Here are the main differences between assets and reference entities:

### In 3.2 and bellow

Product Assets:

- hold files (images, documents, videos, etc)
- are not flexible
- vary by channel and sometime by locale
- can be categorized
- product attributes (asset collection) cannot be localizable nor scopable

Reference entities:

- represents an object (color, fabric, supplier)
- with flexible properties
- that can be linked to products

### In 4.0 and above:

Product assets have been totally revamped and are now really close to reference entities with a lot of improvements:

- transformations
- naming conventions (to guess properties from other properties)
- product link rules (to automatically link assets to products)
- media links to be able to load images, documents and video from outside the PIM

Comment: Thank you Julien Sanchez. Do you have any idea on how to develop customise connector for magento 2 and akeneo for both import and export of products?

Comment: I would recommend to use a Middleware for that, that exports the Magento2 Products via API and imports them via Akeneo API. Or you have a look at https://www.akeneo.com/de/akeneo-onboarder/ (depending on the akeneo solution you're using)